# For each with unknown comparison

Tags: c#

I have a program that generates a report based on a users input somewhere else. This report is forever changing so I can never compare anything to a constant since that constant would change in a day or so.

Currently my report generates something like this. 
Name Value

> A 5
>
> A 10
>
> A 15
>
> B 1
>
> B 2
>
> B 3

What I want to do is say every time the letter is the same add the number from the other column - I thought about a for loop but I don't have anything to compare it with

So for example every time A is printed add its corresponding values to give

> A=30

Is this double without a constant to compare it to?

EDIT:- I have edited the above figures. If you imagine a database that has descriptions and amounts - I want to say For Each time A is printed add up any value associated with A then for each time B is printed add up the values printed with B e.t.c

Comment: Without knowing what kind of data you're handling it's hard to recommend anything specific. I'd look at `GroupBy` if I were you.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't understand anything here?

Comment: From what I can work out, the op loads in `A`'s and `B`'s and he wants a counter of how many of each... is this correct? what have you tried?

Comment: There are only 3 A's , so how come answer is A6?

Comment: @Connor Further to Stefan's comment, can you please provide an example of what you are trying to achieve and the code that demonstrates an attempt to solve the problem? Ideally, can you please distil the problem into a short, but workable sandbox so we can fill the gap (ie, the solution).

Comment: I have edited my original post to be slightly clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to store the letter in a dictionnary structure as key and add up the value.

Something like this

```
Dictionary<string, int> result = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for(int i = 0; i < data.Count ; i++)
{
    string line = data[i];
    string[] element  = line.Split(' '); //assuming your data is a string like in your example
    string key = element[0];
    int value = int.Parse(key[1]);
    result[key] += value;
}
```

**This code was not tested**. It's just a a suggestion that needs to be adapted to your input data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming op is trying to do as @Sayse says

```
var counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();

void UpdateCounts(string input)
{
    var inputDataArray = input.Split(' '); //no validation done on data
    var charFromInput = inputDataArray[0]; 
    int currentCount;
    if (counts.TryGetValue(charFromInput, out currentCount))
        counts[charFromInput] = currentCount + int.Parse(inputDataArray[1]);
    else
        counts.Add(charFromInput, int.Parse(inputDataArray[1]));
}
```

To use/show the count, use
    counts[input.Split(' ')[0]]; //no validation here either

Comment: This is what I was assuming the author is more or less asking for as well. Make sure to update the dictionary with currentCount though as int is not a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's *state the problem*. Having a *text file* (report)

```
  A 1 bla-bla-bla
  A 2 something
  A 3 45 66 996
  B 4 ?
  B 5 2223
  B 6 data
  C 7 anything
```

we want to create an *aggregated report* by *grouping by* 1st column, *summing up* the 2nd one and *ignoring* other columns 
(if they exist):

```
  A = 6
  B = 15
  C = 7
```

If it's your case, then *Linq* solution can be

```
  var result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\MyReport.txt")
    .Select(line => line
       .Split(new Char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .GroupBy(items => items[0], items => int.Parse(items[1]))
    .Select(chunk => String.Format("{0} = {1}", chunk.Key, chunk.Sum())));
  ...

  Console.Write(result);
```

If you want a `Dictionary<String, int>` all you have to modify the Linq:

```
  var dict = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\MyReport.txt")
    .Select(line => line
       .Split(new Char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .GroupBy(items => items[0], items => int.Parse(items[1]))
    .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, chunk => chunk.Sum());

  ...
  // return 6
  Console.Write(dict["A"]);
```